# How to add item to inventory based on tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would I recieve an item based on the tag that my raycast detect?

Let's assume that there is a Copper Sword on the ground,
and I press "F" to pick it up.

Now the script should detect the tag "CopperSword" and Place one Copper Sword in the inventory, or if the tag happend to be "IronSword", one Iron Sword should be placed in the inventory, and so on.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 position;
    private Vector3 target;
    public int range = 2;

    Inventory inv;
    public GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {
        inv = player.GetComponent<Inventory>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        position = gameObject.transform.position;
        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        target = position + Camera.main.transform.forward * range;

        if (Physics.Linecast(position, target, out raycastHit))
        {
            // Shows which object that the Raycast collided with
            Debug.Log(raycastHit.collider.gameObject);
        }

        // Recieve an item based on the Tag
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            if (raycastHit.collider.tag == "CopperSword")
            {
                inv.copperSword += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could just hard-code each "if-statement" to add each specific item, but that doesn't feel very tempting if I had alot of items. So there must be an easier way to approach this.

Comment: You should use raycastHit.collider.gameObject where gameObject can contain all the inventory objects. These Inventory objects should be inherited from common object like ObjectsWhichCanBePicked as base class and inherited in class Sword which is inherited in IronSword and CopperSword.

Comment: While I don't have this knowledge yet, it gives me a starting Point to what to read and learn about in order to make this work. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

"Shall the clay say to him that fashioneth it, what makest thou?" The Bible, Isaiah, 45:9